# jQuery UI sortable dynamic target not working

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, dynamically-generated

I have two tables in my html. The first is loaded on page load, the second is generated on button click.
My sortable function does not apply to the generated table.

Can you explain why?

Here is my Javascript **some.js**:

```
// sort all kinds of tables
$(function(){
  $('table').sortable();
});

// generate new table
$(document).on('click','#test',function(){

  let str = "<table>
               <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>2</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>"

  let content = $.parseHTML(str)

  $('#main').html(content);
  
})
```

And here the actual html file **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="jquery/3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.13.1.js"></script>
    <script defer src="some.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="main">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <input type="button" id="test" value="Generate Table" onclick="">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The generated table does not exist in the DOM in the ready event when you call $('table').sortable(); The table is added to the DOM later as response to the click event. You should call $('table').sortable(); after you add the table to the dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated table does not exist in the DOM in the ready event when you call $('table').sortable(); The table is added to the DOM later as response to the click event. You should call $('table').sortable(); after you add the table to the dom

This should work:

```
$(document).on('click','#test',function(){

  let str = "<table>
               <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>2</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>"

  let content = $.parseHTML(str)

  $('#main').html(content);
  $('#main table').sortable();
})
```

Comment: Why does this work? Please add a brief explanation in your answer